# How to show a dialog from a Console application with Windows 7 styled buttons?

Tags: winforms, windows-7, console-application

When I create a WinForm with a button it appears like this:

[image]

But when I invoke the same form from a console application it appears like this

[image]

Why are they different? How to make a window like the first one to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles(v=vs.80).aspx